# How to add Input Modifiers in C++

Tags: c++, unreal-engine5, unreal

I have a blank Input Mapping Context to which I add the Input Actions that I require at specific times during my game. For example, when I make a roll, I simply add the camera movement Input Action and use this Input Mapping Context so that the user can only use the camera and cannot walk, interact, attack or make other actions while rolling.

I'm doing the same thing for another use case (user is attacking, so it can move the camera and also can use WSAD), but I'm having a hard time setting the Input Modifiers. As of now, the keys WASD will trigger the moving action but due to the lack of modifiers all keys make the character move forwards.

I attached an image with the description of the function giving me trouble. I don't know how to use the second `FInputActionValue CurrentValue` parameter, nor understand it's description.

Please note that I'm aware that people usually just manually create several Input Mapping Context in the editor and just swap between them, but my goal is to do this on runtime.

[image: Current code]

```c++
InputDataAsset->BlankMappingContext->MapKey(InputDataAsset->MoveInputAction, EKeys::W);
InputDataAsset->BlankMappingContext->MapKey(InputDataAsset->MoveInputAction, EKeys::S);
InputDataAsset->BlankMappingContext->MapKey(InputDataAsset->MoveInputAction, EKeys::A);
InputDataAsset->BlankMappingContext->MapKey(InputDataAsset->MoveInputAction, EKeys::D);

UInputModifier Modifier;
Modifier.ModifyRaw(Subsystem->GetPlayerInput(), );
        
TArray<TObjectPtr<UInputModifier>> Modifiers;
Modifiers.Add(Modifier);
InputDataAsset->MoveInputAction->Modifiers = Modifiers;
```